# use a variable in multiple file in python ( like extern )with out assigning the variable instead using the input variable( without using files )

Tags: python, python-2.7

*File 1 ( **a1.py** ) :*

```
a=input("Input : ")

b=a

print("File1 end")
```

*Output :*

```
Input : 4
File1 end
```

*File 2 ( **a2.py** ) :*

```
import a1
print("Output : "+a1.b)
```

Output :

```
Input : 2
File1 end
Output : 2
```

*Expected Output(**After Running a2.py** ):*

```
Output : 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you expect cannot be done in python.
At the time of running **a2.py**, it compiles **a1.py** and stores the input in memory and as soon as the script ends, the memory is deallocated. So you can't expect python to store your variables after end of script unless you use **files**.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of the variable is as it should be and the output you've observed is correct:

```
a=input("Input : ") # a = 2
b=a # b = 2, a = 2

import a1
print("Output : "+a1.b) # a1.b = 2, since b = 2
```

If you want the output to be 4 when entering 2, you have several possibilities, e.g. change the assignment to `b=2*a`.